# ajax data is a string not an array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using jquery ajax to send some data to a php file

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'dosomething.php',
            data: {list:orderNew}
            });
```

Which is sending this to the php

```
$list = $_GET['list'];
```

print $list gives me this:

```
  list[4]=null&list[1]=null&list[2]=4&list[12]=null&list[11]=null&list[3]=null
```

I was hoping to get it as an array so i could do this on my php file

```
 foreach($list as $key => $value) {
            if($value == "null"){
                $value = 0;
            }
}
```

How can a send the list[] data as an actually array so php reads it as an array or turn the string into an array so i can do my foreach on my php page?

Comment: [Use](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: Use [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
parse_str($list, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [list] => Array
        (
            [4] => null
            [1] => null
            [2] => 4
            [12] => null
            [11] => null
            [3] => null
        )

)
```

Comment: ok so how can a make my php foreach work now so i can get the $key and $value?

Comment: Use `foreach ($arr['list'] as $key => $value) {`.

Answer (score -1):

you must use jsonencode on serverside, and then jn client:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'JSON',
            url: 'dosomething.php',
            data: {list:orderNew}
            });
```

Comment: if i change type to JSON what do i put as my php ?

Comment: This is for modifying what is returned by the server, it has nothing to do with what gets sent to the server. It is also syntactically incorrect because type: should be "POST" or "GET" (or any of the other valid ones), you probably meant `dataType`